# How to store file in amazon which expire in one hour using carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I recently implemented file uploading using carrier-wave with Amazon S3 storage.

I want to generate, or make available, the S3 URL only for one hour. After that the link should expire.

How can I do this using carrier-wave?

Comment: What have you tried to do? Stack Overflow requests you show an effort, not just ask a question.

Comment: Here's a step-by-step walkthrough with accompanying code: https://medium.com/@carlosramireziii/secure-file-download-urls-in-rails-d52128b24311#.tubaua8va

Answer (score 1):

The way to handle this is to use a presigned URL for the S3 file.  Once you upload the file using carrier wave, you access the actual S3 URL and use AWS::S3 to presign it with an expiration time.  For example, if the key (file name) in your S3 bucket is "my_file", you could do this:

```
# Your Model
def presigned_url
  s3 = AWS::S3.new
  bucket = s3.buckets["MyBucket"]
  object = bucket.objects["my_file"]
  object.url_for(:read, secure:true, expires:1.hour)
end
```

The URL returned will be valid for 1 hour and then will never work again.

To use this, you will need to include the aws-s3 gem in your Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
gem "aws-s3"
```

Comment: thanks for the response.... i used 'config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 60                             # (in seconds) => 10 minutes' to expire the ur.now when i click the url i am getting **<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<RequestId>F936007949CDA7C9</RequestId>
<Expires>2014-01-30T15:46:27Z</Expires>
<HostId>
gvErTgANourjWZB0kIROqcbiUhDgGsJkXdAQvnsXANixIlMbSSDeu/zTxlIZ23r+
</HostId>
<ServerTime>2014-01-30T15:46:30Z</ServerTime></Error>**xml error form amazon.but i wants to hand this error to display error message to the user.can you help me?

Comment: 60 is only 1 minute - did you mean 600?

Comment: Please ask another question with a code sample to get help on how to show this error to the user.

Comment: how can i access the file again once the url is expired. I have asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805094/how-to-access-the-file-from-amazon-s3-expired-url but didnt get the answer

Comment: The answer there is correct.  The URL is only valid until it expires.  Once it has expired, you can no longer use it.  The file is still stored safely, but the presigned url is useless.  You could run that code again to create a new temporary URL.