# how to access the file from amazon s3 expired url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to access the file from amazon web service s3.

But i am getting error of expired url. Does the expired url deletes the file? Or can it be access by regenerating new url?
How can i regenerate the new url?

Comment: You can make your object public.

Comment: What do you want? A public file or one, you can only access the file with a specific URL / an IAM user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either

- Generate a new pre-signed URL.
- Access the file via an S3 API.

If you can't do any of that, you can't access the file.